# Create a folder inside documents folder in iOS apps

Tags: iphone, directory, new-operator, document, nsfilemanager

I just want to create new folders in the documents folder of my iPhone app.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 330, accepted):

I do that the following way:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder
```

Comment: You might want to change the third line to
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/MyFolder"];
since NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains doesn't return trailing slashes.

Comment: I fixed the code to use the more correct "stringByAppendingPathComponent", which does the right thing regardless of either input string having a "/" or not.

Comment: I am using this way to create a folder in documents folder. But it works fine in iphone 3gs with ios 5.0.1 , but on iphone 4 with ios 4.3.3 it fails to create the folder and the app then crashes. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Vladimir I cannot see because I have installed the app without apple licence. It tries to create /User/Documents/MyAppName . On my 3gs with 5.0.1 it works fine. On iphone 4 with 4.3.3 it fails.

Comment: using ls -l on both phones I see that the one that works has:
-drwxrwxrwx   5 mobile mobile  238 Aug 13 18:12 Documents
The one that does not:
-drwxr-xr-x  3 root   mobile  102 Aug 13 18:08 Documents

How do I change it?

Comment: @Panos, sorry dunno about jailbroken devices. Anyway, path you've mentioned is outside the application sandbox? May be that worth separate question

Comment: @Vladimir Yes that path is outside the app sandbox. This is the Full path in the phones unix filesystem "/User/Documents/MyAppName". Maybe I won't have this problem when I get my Developers License and I install the app as it should :)

Answer (score 15):

Swift 3 Solution:

```
private func createImagesFolder() {
        // path to documents directory
        let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
        if let documentDirectoryPath = documentDirectoryPath {
            // create the custom folder path
            let imagesDirectoryPath = documentDirectoryPath.appending("/images")
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagesDirectoryPath) {
                do {
                    try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: imagesDirectoryPath,
                                                    withIntermediateDirectories: false,
                                                    attributes: nil)
                } catch {
                    print("Error creating images folder in documents dir: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on Manni's answer, but [paths objectAtIndex:0] is the standard way of getting the application's Documents Directory

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW6

> Because the
>   NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
>   function was designed originally for
>   Mac OS X, where there could be more
>   than one of each of these directories,
>   it returns an array of paths rather
>   than a single path. In iOS, the
>   resulting array should contain the
>   single path to the directory. Listing
>   3-1 shows a typical use of this
>   function.
>
> Listing 3-1  Getting the path to the
>   application’s Documents directory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I think the simplest way to retrieve the documents directory path is: `NSString* path = [@"~/Documents" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];`

Answer (score 9):

I don't like "[paths objectAtIndex:0]" because if Apple adds a new folder starting with "A", "B" oder "C", the "Documents"-folder isn't the first folder in the directory.

Better:

```
NSString *dataPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/MyFolder"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder
```

Comment: See Tim's answer. Using NSSearchPathForDirectoryiesInDomains is the standard way of retrieving a users Documents directory.

Comment: If Apple decides to rename the Documents directory to "MyDocuments" (or similar), your approach won't work either.

Answer (score 8):

The **Swift 2** solution:

```
let documentDirectoryPath: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first!
if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(documentDirectoryPath) {
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(documentDirectoryPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)

        } catch let createDirectoryError as NSError {
            print("Error with creating directory at path: \(createDirectoryError.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

This works fine for me,

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *appSupportDir = [fm URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentsDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSURL* dirPath = [[appSupportDir objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFolderName"];

NSError*    theError = nil; //error setting
if (![fm createDirectoryAtURL:dirPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                           attributes:nil error:&theError])
{
   NSLog(@"not created");
}
```

Comment: It should be NSDocumentDirectory instead of NSDocumentsDirectory

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4.0**

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
// Get documents folder
let documentsDirectory: String = paths.first ?? ""
// Get your folder path
let dataPath = documentsDirectory + "/yourFolderName"
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath) {
    // Creates that folder if not exists
    try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
}
```

Comment: how to write data into newly created directory?

Answer (score 1):

Following code may help in creating directory :

```
-(void) createDirectory : (NSString *) dirName {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Fetch path for document directory
dataPath = (NSMutableString *)[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:dirName];

NSError *error;

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't create directory error: %@", error);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"directory created!");
}

NSLog(@"dataPath : %@ ",dataPath); // Path of folder created

}
```

Usage :

```
[self createDirectory:@"MyFolder"];
```

Result :

directory created!

dataPath : /var/mobile/Applications/BD4B5566-1F11-4723-B54C-F1D0B23CBC/Documents/MyFolder

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 1.2 and iOS 8**

Create custom directory (name = "MyCustomData") inside the documents directory but only if the directory does not exist.

```
// path to documents directory
let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String

// create the custom folder path
let myCustomDataDirectoryPath = documentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/MyCustomData")

// check if directory does not exist
if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(myCustomDataDirectoryPath) == false {

    // create the directory
    var createDirectoryError: NSError? = nil
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(myCustomDataDirectoryPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: &createDirectoryError)

    // handle the error, you may call an exception
    if createDirectoryError != nil {
        println("Handle directory creation error...")
    }

}
```