# Where should I saved information specific to iphone session?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I need to save a list created by the user of my app somewhere on his/her iphone. Any idea what technique is best for this ?

Comment: In order to improve the usefulness of this question (and in order to justify your final choice of the "correct" answer), please give more details. What type of data is in the lists you're saving? How many entries do you need to support? Would simple key-value pairs do the trick, or do you need to persist complex records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in SQLite database, or even a simple text file.  I'd use the sql option, but here's an example of [file i/o](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Directory_Handling_and_File_I/O_-_A_Worked_Example).

Answer (score 1):

Save files in the app's document directory.  A plist is a good format for such files.

For information on accessing the document directory see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762836/iphone-create-folder-inside-documents-folder/1762862#1762862)