# Can I create Directories other than standard directories in iOS App?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm developing an iPad App for displaying PDF and presentations . 
but they needs to be  kept in specific directory structure..
can i create Subdirectories in App?
for e.g.

1) Root directory->Dr1098->Sample.pdf

Root directory is my App directory.

Comment: hi i hope this one will help u. [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762836/iphone-create-folder-inside-documents-folder

Comment: @JamesWebster if i would hv enough time,then y not.

Comment: @AppleVijay : Yes dats the same i was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is possible

see Link below. The image sums it up quite well. Also note you can't access the root directory only certain directories in each app i.e documents.

[Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can create sub-directories inside the Documents folder.  You should be keeping most of the content you create inside that documents folder (or a subfolder of it).

[Here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_on_iOS_4_%28iPhone%29) is a good reference guide for dealing with directories in iOS