# Create A Subfolder On iOS App Installation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I would like to have an images folder created inside of the documents folder of my app to house a bunch of images I download at a later point. How do I create this folder when the app is first installed? I am sure it's a setting in Xcode that I just cannot find...

Comment: Have you tried searching?

Comment: There're no settings for this. You have to create one in code, using `NSFileManager`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a folder inside documents folder in iOS apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762836/create-a-folder-inside-documents-folder-in-ios-apps)

Comment: trojanfoe : +1
Maybe you looking for something like FileSharing. If you activate this, you could be able to throw you files and folder directly to your app directory via iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I create my directories on the first run of the app, placed in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
  (NSDictionary*)launchOptions {

/////////////////////////////////////////
// Create Content directories if needed
/////////////////////////////////////////

NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;
NSString *newDir;
NSString *thumbNails;
NSString *largeImages;

filemgr =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                               NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];

// Picture Directory
newDir = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myPictures"];
if(![filemgr fileExistsAtPath:newDir])
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/myPictures"]];
    NSError *error;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myPictures"] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    [data writeToFile:newDir atomically:YES];
}

// Nested Thumbnail Directory
thumbNails =[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myPictures/thumb"];
if(![filemgr fileExistsAtPath:thumbNails])
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/myPictures/thumb"]];
    NSError *error;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myPictures/thumb"] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    [data writeToFile:thumbNails atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: While this is not a particularly expensive process, it's always best to defer this kind of processing until it's needed. I.E., perform this action when the first file needs to be stored.