# How to access all files and folders names that contain string "xyz" in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

If I give the string `xyz`, the program should search all files and folders from the whole harddisk that contain the string `xyz` in name. How to write code for this in Cocoa using Xcode and Objective-C in MAC OS? Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a list of files in a directory with a glob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499673/getting-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-with-a-glob)

Answer (score 2):

Try Spotlight by the means of `NSMetadataQuery`

Comment: Thanks Pierre Bernard. i got it thru NSMetadataQuery