# NSPredicate endswith multiple files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nspredicate

I am trying to filter an array using a predicate checking for files ending in a set of extensions. How could I do it?

Would something close to **'self endswith in %@'** work? Thanks!

```
NSArray * dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath error:nil];
NSArray * files = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS %@",
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@".mp4", @".mov", @".m4v", @".pdf", @".doc", @".xls", nil]
    ]];
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You don't want contains for an array, you want in. You also ideally want to filter by the path extension. So

```
NSArray *extensions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"mp4", @"mov", @"m4v", @"pdf", @"doc", @"xls", nil];
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath error:nil];
NSArray *files = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension IN %@", extensions]];
```

Comment: +1 far superior to my answer. I can't believe I didn't think of this.  Kudos to you.

Answer (score 3):

**edit** Martin's answer is far superior to this one.  His is the correct answer.

---

There are a couple ways to do it.  Probably the simplest would just be to build a giant OR predicate:

```
NSArray *extensions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@".mp4", @".mov", @".m4v", @".pdf", @".doc", @".xls", nil];
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *extension in extensions) {
  [subpredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH %@", extension]];
}
NSPredicate *filter = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];

NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath error:nil];
NSArray *files = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

This will create a predicate that's equivalent to:

```
SELF ENDSWITH '.mp4' OR SELF ENDSWITH '.mov' OR SELF ENDSWITH '.m4v' OR ....
```