# Get list of files with specific extensions at a specified path in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm pretty new to Objective-C. I'm developing a Cocoa application.
Currently I'm looking for the equivalent of this C# code in Objective C:

```
string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(DownloadPath, "*.jpg");
```

The returned strings need not necessarily be full path, since all I need is the file names. I have tried NSFileManager but so far no good yet. Thank you.

EDIT: What I've tried with NSFileManager:

```
[someFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
```

I also want to ask: what is the format of 'path'? This sounds easy, but I'm completely clueless about MAC OS file system. The path that I'm using is from [NSOpenPanel URLs], and they looks like this:

```
file://localhost/Users/alex/Movies/
```

Sometimes I get the results, but some other time The returned NSArray is just empty. I'm pretty confused about this so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT2:
The answer here: [NSPredicate endswith multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032541/nspredicate-endswith-multiple-files), is probably a better choice. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSPredicate endswith multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032541/nspredicate-endswith-multiple-files)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This code should work:

```
NSArray *dirFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
NSArray *jpgFiles = [dirFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.jpg'"]];
```

Comment: Im using NSOpenPanel to get the path. The path looks like this: file://localhost/alex/temp/Louis/ , and I am not getting anything using [NSFileManager contentsOf...], basically an empty NSArray. Can you tell me if the URL I am using for the path is correct?

Comment: You need to convert your url('file://...') into a normal POSIX path. You can do it using this: `NSString *filepath = [fileURL path];`.

Answer (score 4):

In fact you need some thing like this

```
NSArray *dirFiles = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsDir] includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray array] options:0 error:nil] ;
NSArray *filteredFiles = [dirFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.absoluteString ENDSWITH '.jpg'"]] ;
```

Because contentsOfDirectoryAtURL: returns array of NSURL's, so using just "self ENDSWITH '.jpg'" will crash.

Answer (score 3):

maybe something along these lines:

```
NSFileManager * fileMan = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSArray * files = [fileMan contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"mypath/blah" error:nil]; 

if (files) 
{
    for(int index=0;index<files.count;index++)
    {
        NSString * file = [files objectAtIndex:index];

        if( [[file pathExtension] compare: @"jpg"] == NSOrderedSame )
        {
            // do something with files that end with .jpg
        }
    }
}

[fileMan release];
```