# How to get the file extension

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nspredicate

How to give multiple check condition in NSPredicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH %@ %@%@ ,doc,pdf,png];
```

it need to work and give me three type and give me output.

Comment: Check this posible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5032607/1169171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
NSArray *ext = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"doc", @"pdf", @"png", nil];
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirPath error:nil];
NSArray *files = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension IN %@", ext]];
```

Comment: As posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032541/nspredicate-endswith-multiple-files/5032607#5032607