# How to filter array and let stay only strings end with .png

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, nsfilemanager

I am reading files from folder, folder contains `.pngs` but I get additionally `Thumb.db` file in every folder and all others are .pngs. I read content as

```
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
```

How to remove all files which contains `.db` in array or to stay just which ends with `.png` ?

Comment: This is a relatively trivial task with a `for..in` loop. What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSPredicate endswith multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032541/nspredicate-endswith-multiple-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think by using NSPredicate method  you can get exact values

```
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
NSString *str              = @".png"
NSPredicate *sPredicate    = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",str];
NSArray *predicateArray    = [directoryContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
```

Answer (score 4):

Idiomatic way of filtering arrays in Cocoa is with [`NSPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/):

```
NSArray *filtered = [directoryContent filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension = png"]];
```

[`pathExtension`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/pathExtension) method mentioned inside the predicate is a method on `NSString` that tries to interpret the string as a filesystem path, and return the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString *path in directoryContent) 
    {
       if ([path hasSuffix:@".png"]) 
       {
          [imageArray addObject: path];
       }
    }

    NSLog (@"Number of images : %d" , [imageArray count]);
```

Comment: NSPredicate is a simpler solution

Comment: Yes it is, even I didn't know that earlier.