# check for file extension in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to check the extensions of files in directory  or search for certain extension amog different extensions , any suggestion to do that for iphone applications

Best regards

Comment: this question is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499673/getting-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-with-a-glob

Answer (score 7):

You can use `NSFileManager's` `-contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` method to get an array with the contents of a directory (as strings). `NSString` has a `-pathExtension` method that makes it easy to get the file extension. All that remains is to iterate over the array looking for strings whose `-pathExtension` matches the extension you're looking for. Alternately, you could probably use `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` to identify the matching strings.

Comment: are there any examples to clarify your wors

Comment: Read Ben Clayton's comment. Your question is pretty much a duplicate of the one linked, and there's some code there that does what I wrote. But out of curiousity and my own desire to write better answers, which part seems difficult?