# display directory contents in uitableview

Tags: ios4, uitableview

i need some help.I have directory which contains multiple files.
I have path for that directory,
i want to display the contents of directory in a uitableview.
Like in each cell a file of that directory.
when tapping that cell i want to open that file in iPhone.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

[Refer to this article for folder listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499673/getting-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-with-a-glob)

then once you've grabbed all the information, use the UITableViewController to display the information in the cells. Then handle each file type depending on what it is (images? videos?) by overriding

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

You can find the documentation and some apple examples [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)