# Count the number of XML files in your project

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to get a count of XML files added to a Xcode project?

Comment: Clarify what "external XML files added to the resources of the project" means, and if possible give an example of such a XML file and how it ended up in your project. Further if possible give the REASON for asking this question.

Comment: I have a project to which i add a certain number of XML files, how do i find out the count of the XML files added?

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory, execute the following command in the console:

```
find . -iname '*.xml' | wc -l
```

This assumes that the xml files were copied to the project directory when they were added. If not, then actual parsing of the project file is required.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am pretty new to ios development, guess this is not new for many but for those who might need help,here is how i solved it-

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.xml'"];
NSArray *onlyXMLs = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
NSLog(@"%d is the count",[onlyXMLs count]);
```

i found the solution from this link - [Getting a list of files in a directory with a glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499673/getting-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-with-a-glob)