# Delete multiple files with names containing a substring efficiently

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsfilemanager

I would like to delete multiple files that contain a substring. Say for example I would like to delete all the files that has the substring `my`. Assume that my directory contains 4 files: **photo.jpg**, **myPhoto.jpg**, **beachMyPhoto.jpg**, **anyPhoto.jpg**, since the term of search is `my` the files that I am interested to delete are **myPhoto.jpg** and **beachMyPhoto.jpg** (case insensitive).

My proposed solution (which I know how to do) is to use `NSFileManager` class, and use the function `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` to read all the directory contents, and then search by a loop for a hit. If a hit is found I delete that file.

What I don't like in my proposed solution is that it is not that efficient especially if the directory contains too many files and the hit is a small number. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You could use the block method indexesOfObjectsPassingTest, but I don't know if that is any faster than your own loop -- it must do some kind of loop internally as well

Comment: May be something in this direction:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499673/getting-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-with-a-glob

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a big array loaded into memory, you can try `-[NSFileManager enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:]`. Since you only want the immediate contents of the directory, you would invoke `-[NSDirectoryEnumerator skipDescendants]` for each directory that it returns.

If your concern is iterating over all of the items in the directory, testing for your match pattern, well that's unavoidable. Any technique you would hope to use has to somehow iterate over all of the items in the directory and test for a match. The only question is whether that iteration is exposed to you or not. In Cocoa, it is. You could drop down to the [`glob()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/glob.3) function if you want an alternative where it isn't.