# List the Versions of all the applications installed in iOS device programmatically

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios9, xcode7

I need to get the Versions of all the installed applications programmatically for non-jailbroken iOS devices.
Is it Possible to achieve this?

Comment: Only if you Jailbreak.

Comment: What is your "use case"? Because Apple don't have a public API to violate user privacy.

Comment: @avi: i guess OP asking for getting version number so i posted the answer anyeay if you have better answer then please put and explain it :)

Answer (score 3):

That's possible, please try the below code.

```
Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
    NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:@selector(defaultWorkspace)];

    for (LSApplicationProxy *apps in [workspace performSelector:@selector(allApplications)])
    {         
        NSString *localizedName = apps.localizedName;

        if([apps.applicationType isEqualToString:@"User"])
        {
            NSLog(@"\nlocalizedName: %@",localizedName);
            NSLog(@"minimumSystemVersion: %@",apps.minimumSystemVersion);
            NSLog(@"fileSharingEnabled: %d",apps.fileSharingEnabled);
            NSLog(@"sdkVersion: %@",apps.sdkVersion);
            NSLog(@"teamID: %@",apps.teamID);
        }
    }
```

For this you need to place 4 classes in your app:

```
LSApplicationWorkspace, LSResourceProxy, LSBundleProxy, LSApplicationProxy.
```

Comment: How can I get the Installed date and  Last Updated date of all the applications ?

Comment: Does apple approve the this code which used  below runtime classes ?
    LSApplicationWorkspace, LSResourceProxy, LSBundleProxy, LSApplicationProxy.

Comment: how to import all LS classes in my class??

Comment: My app was rejected while using this, please don't use this for submission to app store.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS8 and before, we can use canOpenUrl to get installed applications which registered schemes. In iOS9, you must add a "white list" into your info.plist file. Only the application in the "white list" can be checked. And the limit count of the "white list" is 50. So you'd better jailbreak your device.

See more information: [How to check particular app is already installed on iphone device or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736756/how-to-check-particular-app-is-already-installed-on-iphone-device-or-not)

Another one: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl.html

Comment: You can do the same in iOS 9, but you have to "pre-declare" which schemes you will be using.