# To differentiate Anti-virus applications from other applications in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, info.plist

I want to know whether there is some unique key in Applications info.plist so that i can differentiate between Antivirus apps and other apps installed on iPhone.

I can get list by using [Application List Installed on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849051/list-the-versions-of-all-the-applications-installed-in-ios-device-programaticall).
All I want to do is differentiate Antivirus Apps from other apps.

Comment: There is a magic and undocumented key "allowSystemWideAccessToAllDataButToPreventFromSecurityIssuesItIsOnlySetForTheBraveAndGoodAppsHoooray". But it is always @NO.