# iPhone app: get shell command output

Tags: ios, shell, nstask

I'm trying to build an app for the iPhone (or iPad, for that matter) in which I want to run some shell commands. The iPhone on which I want it to work is *not* jailbroken.

The `system()` command *seems* to work in executing a shell command, but output and input is of course still a problem. I learned that `NSTask` may be used for these kinds of things and that it's present, though not documented. (Including the Mac `NSTask.h` seems to work perfectly)

Now the problem is that when executing this code:

```
NSTask *task;
task=[[NSTask alloc] init];
task.launchPath=@"/usr/bin/ls";
task.arguments=[NSArray array];
NSPipe *pipe=[NSPipe pipe];
task.standardOutput=pipe;
task.standardError=pipe;
NSFileHandle *output=pipe.fileHandleForReading;
pipe=[NSPipe pipe];
task.standardInput=pipe;
[task launch];
```

where `pipe` is for future I/O, it generates an error reading:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'
```

I already tried quite a few possible paths for the unix `bin` directory but either I can't find it or my app doesn't have permissions to list files. -.-

**How do I execute shell commands on an iPhone while having control over both input and output of that command?**

Comment: if it's not jailbroken then it won't work. Additionally, this is probably the singularly worst way to list the contents of a directory. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499673/getting-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-with-a-glob

Comment: The `ls` is nust an example, it could have been any other command. But why only jailbroken? Why can't I just execute a shell command?

Comment: Because it's not permitted in iOS. Anything that involves the direct creation of another process will be denied by security policy.

Comment: Well... That fails, I guess :) Post that as an answer and if there isn't anyone else able to help, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any attempts to directly create a secondary process in iOS will be denied by the security policy unless you are running on a jailbroken phone.