# Objective-C get list of files and subfolders in a directory

Tags: objective-c

What is the trick to get an array list of full file/folder paths from a given directory?
I'm looking to search a given directory for files ending in .mp3 and need the full path name that includes the filename.

```
NSArray* dirs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sourcePath error:Nil];

NSArray* mp3Files = [dirs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.mp3'"]];
```

this only returns the file name not the path

Comment: How is `dirs` populated?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's probably best to enumerate the array using a block, which can be used to concatenate the path and the filename, testing for whatever file extension you want:

```
NSArray* dirs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sourcePath
                                                                    error:NULL];
NSMutableArray *mp3Files = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[dirs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *filename = (NSString *)obj;
    NSString *extension = [[filename pathExtension] lowercaseString];
    if ([extension isEqualToString:@"mp3"]) {
        [mp3Files addObject:[sourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

To use a predicate on URLs I would do it this way:

```
NSURL *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
NSArray * dirContents = 
      [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:bundleRoot
        includingPropertiesForKeys:@[] 
                           options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                             error:nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension='.mp3'"];
NSArray *mp3Files = [directoryContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This question may be a duplicate: [Getting a list of files in a directory with a glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499673/getting-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-with-a-glob)

There is also the `NSDirectoryEnumerator` object which is great for iterating through files in a directory.

Comment: mp3Files here also only contains file names and not the complete path to the file.