# Fetch images from bundle into array

Tags: ios, bundle

Have created one folder say 'cat' in bundle which contains images. Now I need to load all that images in an array. how to do that programmatically ?

Comment: This is already answered in [this post][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499673/getting-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-with-a-glob

Comment: NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cat" ofType:nil];

Comment: @RichardRuiter ya but is gives the list of all files in the bundle.. but i need only the files within specific folder. can you please help me in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cat"];
NSArray *fileList = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath error:&error];
```

Edit:

Your folder must be added by reference. Drag your folder into your project in xCode and select "Create folder references for any added folders"

[image]

Comment: tried that too.. getting nil in fileList

Comment: check you have your folder cat inside of your project in Finder. This code should works

Comment: checked it is right there.. in fact I have added that folder from project to the bundle, so that is not the problem

Comment: ohh.. just forgot to add reference.. THANK YOU SO MUCH.. :) @SonGoku68