# NSDirectoryEnumerator iterated element can't compare suffix

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

I am using `NSDirectoryEnmerator` to find all file with a suffix of `png` and `jpg` with following code:

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtURL:containerURL includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray array] options:0 errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
    // handle error
    return NO;
}];

NSString *fileOrDirectory = nil;
while ((fileOrDirectory = [directoryEnumerator nextObject])) {
    if([fileOrDirectory hasSuffix:@".jpg"] || [fileOrDirectory hasSuffix:@".png"]){
        NSLog(@" find a image file %@", fileOrDirectory );
    }

}
```

But there is an error said that `NSURL` don't have a method `hasSuffix`

[image]

What happened and how to make this work? what does the type of the iterated elements exactly? the above code was frequently suggested by [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5573949/2288944) and was presumed to be a `NSString` but it can't work

Comment: According to the error: `[directoryEnumerator nextObject]` returns apparently a `NSURL` object, not a `NSString` object. Replace maybe `fileOrDirectory = [directoryEnumerator nextObject]` with `fileOrDirectory = [directoryEnumerator nextObject].absoluteString`? The diff from the linked answer is `enumeratorAtURL:` vs `enumartorAtPath:` I guess, which explains the different.

Comment: @Larme I have found plenty of [code snippet](https://eezytutorials.com/ios/nsdirectoryenumerator-by-example.php#.Wa-0jtMjHBI) on the internet that using a `NSString`, are they all wrong and misleading?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my previous comment: "The diff from the linked answer is enumeratorAtURL: vs enumartorAtPath: I guess, which explains the different class of object returned"

Answer (score 1):

The `enumeratorAtURL` method works with `NSURL` objects rather than strings (which the exception reason clearly reveals), you can simply compare the `pathExtension`:

```
if ([fileOrDirectory.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || 
    [fileOrDirectory.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"png"]) { ...
```